# Azure IoT Hub - Publish and subscribe to same MQTT topic

Tags: mqtt, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I want to publish a message to IoT Hub and also receive the message via the same topic. I connected to IoT Hub and then subscribed to the same topic to which i send the messages, but I don't receive any message. As Client I am using MQTTX windows. Messages are sent and received correctly at the cloud endpoint (telemetry data). 
 Here is a screenshot from my MQTT client: [MQTT Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrWu6.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using MQTTX as a leaf device to IoT Edge in a transparent gateway pattern, where edge will just pass through messages to IoTHub.

IoTHub does not support custom topic or respond back on the same topic so this   "devices/plc2/messages/events/topic" will not work

Subscription to devices/{device_id}/messages/devicebound/# will work but you will need to explicitly send C2D message for that device_id as a response

Comment: Ok. I also made some further testing. Publishing and Subscribing to topics which are defined in the edge manifest works well - But of course that is then only local communication. How is it possible to create a C2D message as a reply to an incoming message? The rule engine does not provide this at first glance - The solution is made with Azure IoT Central

Comment: Also for my test it does not matter if i communicate through the IoT Edge as transparent gateway, or if i communicate directly with the IoT Hub. I just want to test the round trip time with one of these communication models

Answer (score 0):

The Azure IoT Hub is not a generic MQTT broker, see more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support).

I do recommend to read also the doc for [Azure IoT Edge MQTT broker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-publish-subscribe?view=iotedge-2020-11).

**UPDATE:**

Based on your needs, such as a *round trip time* test, the following is an example how can be achieved this *loopback* in the  Azure IoT Central. Note, that the Iot Central App has a built-in great features to simplify your test without using additional azure resource such as an Azure function.

The concept of this example is based on the following:

- [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iotcentral/1.2-previewdataplane/devices/run-command) for invoking a durable command (Queuing command) to generate a C2D Message.
- Using the *Data Transformation* for exporting a message to the webhook destination

First of all, we have to create a device template (in my example loopback) for our test:

```
{
"@id": "dtmi:rk2022iotcfree:loopback_24v;1",
"@type": "Interface",
"contents": [
    {
        "@id": "dtmi:rk2022iotcfree:loopback_24v:message;1",
        "@type": "Command",
        "displayName": {
            "en": "Message"
        },
        "name": "message",
        "request": {
            "@type": "CommandPayload",
            "displayName": {
                "en": "Info"
            },
            "name": "Info",
            "schema": {
                "@type": "Object",
                "displayName": {
                    "en": "Object"
                },
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "displayName": {
                            "en": "ts"
                        },
                        "name": "ts",
                        "schema": "dateTime"
                    },
                    {
                        "displayName": {
                            "en": "msg"
                        },
                        "name": "msg",
                        "schema": "string"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "durable": true
    },
    {
        "@id": "dtmi:rk2022iotcfree:loopback_24v:counter;1",
        "@type": "Telemetry",
        "displayName": {
            "en": "Counter"
        },
        "name": "counter",
        "schema": "double"
    },
    {
        "@id": "dtmi:rk2022iotcfree:loopback_24v:time;1",
        "@type": "Telemetry",
        "displayName": {
            "en": "Timestamp"
        },
        "name": "time",
        "schema": "double"
    }
],
"displayName": {
    "en": "loopback"
},
"@context": [
    "dtmi:iotcentral:context;2",
    "dtmi:dtdl:context;2"
]
```

}

Once we have the device template, we can create a device (in my example *device1*) with assigning to this device template (loopback).

Now, we need to declare a destination webhook endpoint:

[image]

where the *Callback UR*L is:

```
https://2a92220d-42e3-4a73-b700-2cb858c9c5e7.azureiotcentral.com/api/devices/device1/commands/message?api-version=1.2-preview
```

and the *Authorization token* is generated as the IoT Central Api token

Next step is declaring a *Data transformation* for this destination endpoint:

```
 import "iotc" as iotc;
 if .device.id == "device1" then
 { 
  request: {
    Info:{
      ts:.enqueuedTime,
      msg:("Feedback from device: id=" + .device.id + ", counter=" + (.telemetry | iotc::find(.name == "counter").value | tostring) + ", time=" + (.telemetry | iotc::find(.name == "time").value | tostring))
    }
  }
}
else
  empty
end
```

That's all at the IoT Central App. Based on the above Data transformation, any received telemetry data message from the device1 is exported to the webhook endpoint for invoking a C2D message.

In my example, for the device side is used my tool for virtual MQTT device (either the [Azure IoT Hub Tester](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1173356/Azure-IoT-Hub-Tester) or [Azure IoT Central Tester](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5322753/Azure-IoT-Central-Tester)), but it can be used any other similar tool or MQTT client.

[image]

As you can see the above screen snippet, the *device1* sent the telemetry data such as a *counter* and *time* and the device received the C2D message:

[image]

As the above screen snippet shows, there are three timestamps. The two highlighted timestamps are represented a round trip time (from the device to the IoT Central and back to the device). The third one is represented a timestamp at the IoT Central app:

```
Start device:     2022-05-19T13:50:06.4213024Z
IoT Central App:  2022-05-19T13:50:07.107Z
End device:       2022-05-19T13:50:13.6934397Z
```

Comment: I know the article. But there is nothing described about subscribing for IoT Hub oder IoT Edge which is helpful. I also tried to subscribe to following topic as stated in the documentation: devices/{device_id}/messages/devicebound/#   Generally i want to measure the roundtrip time from sending a mqtt message until receiving the reply

Comment: @ricktauss, Have a look at my update

Comment: I will try to implement it that way that you explained and then respnd How did you get the subdomain for the IoT Central domain "2a92220d.......c9c5e7.azureiotcentral?  Thank you!

Comment: @ricktauss, it's the Application ID, you can get it from the portal/Application/Management page or from the Api token (SharedAccessSignature sr=2a92220d-42e3-4a73-b700-2cb858c9c5e7&sig=wy...)

Comment: i have tried now your solution and it is exactly working with your explanation. Many thanks!